# Parsing XML files to CSV - NameError

Tags: python, xml, csv, parsing

I am parsing large projects with many thousand XML files for specific Elements and Attributes. I have managed to print all the Elements and Attributes I want but I cannot write them into a CSV Table. It would be great if I could get every occurrence of every Element/Attribute under the respective headers. The Problem is that I get "NameError: name 'X' is not defined", I do not know how to restructure, everything seemed to be working fine with my variables until I moved them to a CSV.

```
from logging import root
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv
import os
path = r'C:\Users\briefe\V'

f = open('jp-elements.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(["Note", "Supplied", "@Certainty", "@Source"])


    #opening files in folder for project
for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if filename.endswith(".xml"):
            fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        #getting the root of each file as my starting point
        for file in fullpath:
            tree = ET.parse(fullpath)
            root = tree.getroot()
            try:
                for note in root.findall('.//note'):
                    notes = note.attrib, note.text
                for supplied in root.findall(".//supplied"):
                    print(supplied.attrib)
                    for suppliedChild in supplied.findall(".//*"):
                        supplies = suppliedChild.tag, suppliedChild.attrib
                #attribute search
                for responsibility in root.findall(".//*[@resp]"):
                    responsibilities = responsibility.tag, responsibility.attrib, responsibility.text
                for certainty in root.findall(".//*[@cert]"):
                    certainties = certainty.tag, certainty.attrib, certainty.text
                writer.writerow([notes, supplies, responsibilities, certainties])
            finally:
                f.close()
```

As was kindly advised I am trying to save results that looked like:

```
{http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0}add {'resp': '#MB', 'status': 'unremarkable'} Nach H gedruckt IV. Abt., V, Anhang Nr.
                     10.
{http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0}date {'cert': 'medium', 'when': '1805-04-09'} 9. April 1805
```

I am trying to save these mixtures of tuples and dictionary items as strings into csv fields. But I get "NameError: name 'notes' is not defined" for example.

XML code example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" type="letter" xml:id="V_100">
   <teiHeader>
</teiHeader>
   <text>
      <body>
         <div type="letter">
            <note type="ig">Kopie</note>
            <p>Erlauben Sie mir, in Ihre Ehrenpforte noch einige Zwick<lb xml:id="V_39-7" rendition="#hyphen"/>steinchen einzuschieben. Philemon und Baucis müssen —
                  wenn<note corresp="#V_39-8">
                  <listPerson type="lineReference">
                     <person corresp="#JP-000228">
                        <persName>
                           <name cert="high" type="reg">Baucis</name>
                        </persName>
                     </person>
                     <person corresp="#JP-003214" ana="†">
                        <persName>
                           <name cert="low" type="reg">Philemon</name>
                        </persName>
                     </person>
                  </listPerson>
            <p>
               <hi rendition="#aq">Der Brief ist vielleicht nicht an den Minister Hardenberg
                  gerichtet,<lb/>
            </p>
            <lb/>
         </div>
      </body>
   </text>
</TEI>
```

Comment: Please post sample XML for us to help. Remember XML is a different data format than the two dimensions of CSV. You appear to be saving tuples of strings and dictionaries (result of `attrib`) to every row. Ideally, scalar strings/numbers should be saved to every CSV row.

Comment: @Parfait I added the results I got from print(). The actual XML might look like this: 
```<choice>
 <sic>cheesemakers</sic>
 <corr resp="#editor" cert="high">peacemakers</corr>
</choice>: for they shall be called the children of God.``` It is all TEI conform but I am looking for many different elements and attributes - I just want the key info - tag, attributes and text all to be added as a string to a csv field

Comment: Why do you want to save nested data within cells of CSV as tuples/dicts will cause? There are ways to parse all individual items to separate cells.

Comment: But still cannot fully help without sample XML required of a [mcve]. Possibly, `notes` is never assigned in one iteration since its `for` loop retrieves nothing. Results indicate XML may have namespaces which can vary by elements. Because of namespaces, always post at least root of XML. Your snippet can be anywhere in document.

Comment: The most important thing is that I want to see if elements and attributes occur in the parsed XML files or not - that is why I am not too fussed about separating the data I get yet because I only care there is an element or not and how many there are. I want to use the same code on different projects that will have slightly different encoding guidelines. That is why I didn't add a XML example at first but now I did - all of the XML files will have the same TEI namespace because they all have the same root.

Comment: @Parfait Thank you for the help. I think the problem is that I cannot access notes because it is in the for loop and my writer.writerow command is outside that for loop. I need to find a way to get all the info from inside the various loops outside into my writerow. .

Comment: Your posted XML is not well-formed. Various elements do not close. I will assume you made changes manually to original in posting here.

Comment: @Parfait Yes, sorry I did not realise it wasn't well formatted. The Texts are very long and I didn't want to post the whole thing here, so I took most of it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted, the XML has a default namespace at root which must be accounted for *every* named reference of an element such as `<note>`. Therefore, consider this adjustment where `notes` will be properly assigned.

```py
nsmp = "http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"

for note in root.findall(f'.//{{{nsmp}}}note'):
    notes = note.attrib, note.text
```

The triple curly brace is to ensure the interpolated string value is enclosed in curly braces which is also the symbol used in F strings. Do note, your code will then also err for `supplies` not being found.

---

However, given your comments, consider a dynamic solution which does not hard code any element name but parses all elements and attributes and flattens the output to CSV format. Below uses nested list/dict comprehensions to parse XML data and migrates to CSV using `csv.DictWriter` which maps dictionaries to field names of a CSV. Also, below uses context manager, `with()`, to write to text and requires no `close()` command.

```py
with open('Output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        f, fieldnames=['element_or_attribute', 'text_or_value']
    )
  
    # MERGES DICTIONARIES OF ELEMENTS AND ATTRIBUTES
    # DICT KEYS REMOVE NAMESPACES AND CHECKS FOR NoneTypes
    # ATTRIBUTES ARE PREFIXED WITH PARENT ELEMENT NAME
    xml_dicts = [{
        **{el.tag.split('}')[1]:(
            el.text.strip() if el.text is not None else el.text
          )}, 
        **{(
            el.tag.split('}')[1]+'_'+k.split('}')[1] 
            if '}' in k 
            else el.tag.split('}')[1]+'_'+k):v 
           for k,v in el.attrib.items()}
    } for i, el in enumerate(root.findall(f'.//*'), start=1)]
    
    # COMBINES ABOVE DICTS INTO FLATTER FORMAT
    csv_dicts = [
        {'element_or_attribute': k, 'text_or_value':v} 
        for d in xml_dicts  
        for k, v in d.items()
    ]
    
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(csv_dicts)
```

Above should be integrated into your loop of files where this processes *one* XML file to *one* CSV.

**CSV Output**

| element_or_attribute | text_or_value |
| --- | --- |
| teiHeader |  |
| text |  |
| body |  |
| div |  |
| div_type | letter |
| note | Kopie |
| note_type | ig |
| p | "Erlauben Sie mir, in Ihre Ehrenpforte noch einige Zwick" |
| lb |  |
| lb_id | V_39-7 |
| lb_rendition | #hyphen |
| note |  |
| note_corresp | #V_39-8 |
| listPerson |  |
| listPerson_type | lineReference |
| person |  |
| person_corresp | #JP-000228 |
| persName |  |
| name | Baucis |
| name_cert | high |
| name_type | reg |
| person |  |
| person_corresp | #JP-003214 |
| person_ana | † |
| persName |  |
| name | Philemon |
| name_cert | low |
| name_type | reg |
| p |  |
| hi | "Der Brief ist vielleicht nicht an den Minister Hardenberg\n gerichtet," |
| hi_rendition | #aq |
| lb |  |
| lb |  |

---

**XML Input** *(corrected for reproducibility)*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" type="letter" xml:id="V_100">
   <teiHeader></teiHeader>
   <text>
      <body>
         <div type="letter">
            <note type="ig">Kopie</note>
            <p>Erlauben Sie mir, in Ihre Ehrenpforte noch einige Zwick<lb xml:id="V_39-7" rendition="#hyphen"/>steinchen einzuschieben. Philemon und Baucis müssen —
                  wenn<note corresp="#V_39-8"/>
                  <listPerson type="lineReference">
                     <person corresp="#JP-000228">
                        <persName>
                           <name cert="high" type="reg">Baucis</name>
                        </persName>
                     </person>
                     <person corresp="#JP-003214" ana="†">
                        <persName>
                           <name cert="low" type="reg">Philemon</name>
                        </persName>
                     </person>
                  </listPerson>
            </p>
            <p>
               <hi rendition="#aq">Der Brief ist vielleicht nicht an den Minister Hardenberg
                  gerichtet,<lb/></hi>
            </p>
            <lb/>
         </div>
      </body>
   </text>
</TEI>
```